# Setting up a dynamic webserver

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, webserver

I want to set up a webserver to use a personal search engine, [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/). This python script already provides a web-ui to query recoll : [recoll-webui](https://github.com/koniu/recoll-webui/). I am able to access recoll from my browser on `http://localhost:8080`, but unable to access that page from other computers on my network.

I have setup a webserver using apache and can access a static page on my computer from other computers on my network. How can I go about forwarding the output that I get on `localhost:8080` to the apache server ?

PS : Just putting a link to `http://localhost:8080` on a static webpage does not work

PS : I'm on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you run the recoll webui by executing the webui-standalone.py program ?

If this is the case, you need to change a line in the file for the server to accept connections from another host:

`-webui.bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=False)
+webui.bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, reloader=False)`

As for running the interface under Apache, I never did it, but it's feasible as far as I know, I think that you need to look at this page in the bottle framework doc:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the network ip address of your computer. On windows, in the CMD, try `ipconfig`, and see what your ip address is. Usually something starting with 192, but it can be 10 or 172 as well. On Linux or OSX use `ip addr` or `ifconfig`. Then use that address instead of `localhost`. (And next time, tell us what OS you're using!)

If this doesn't work, you need to change your firewall settings to allow for port 8080 and 80.

Comment: using "sudo netstat -anltp" gives me :

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21698/python.

So I think I just have to open port 8080, so I ran "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT",  but I still cannot access <my-ip>:8080 only localhost:8080 or <my-ip>:80 .

Comment: Are you sure about `--sport 8080` ? I would use `--dport 8080` instead, as the port is for destination

Comment: I tried both... they did not work